# ESRI/Leaflet FeatureLayer

Tags: esri-leaflet

ESRI mapservice layer features not loaded entirely when it loaded with L.esri.featureLayer. Features which are visible at a particular zoom level gets loaded and rest all not available for further processing. Only when zoomed out, the map extent expands and all features are loaded.

Comment: I think you will need to add a bit more information for anyone to be able to help. Screen shots, code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is by design that esri leaflet's `L.esri.featureLayer` only fetches features from a service that are located within the current extent of the map.

check out the sample below for an alternative example which uses `L.esri.query` to make a request for whatever features you want.

http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/feature-layer-snapshot.html